# How to log out from a guest account?

Tags: discussion

So yesterday I posted a question as a guest, then closed the browser tab Now when I open again this website I see I'm still logged in with the username I chose, even though I did not make a 'complete signup' with setting a password, and there doesn't seem to be a logout option. So is there a way to actually log out without having to close the whole browser window?

Comment: Can you give the url of the website and the browser/os you use?

Answer (score 4):

Your account is not yet registered and you're identified by the browser cookie

[image]

If you delete the browser cookie, the site will not be able to remember you